# RequireJS doesn't load modules on crosswalk apps

Tags: android, requirejs, intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

My app works correctly in mobile browsers. It even works correctly in Intel XDK emulators. But when I build it as Crosswalk Android and run on device, my app doesn't work. I found out that requireJS just doesn't load modules that it should to load.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a specific example with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found. The problem was with wrong case of path constants. Windows ignores the mixed cases in string paths, because it case independent. But Android (Linux based OS) can't ignore case difference.